# HowTo: Run "SUDO" code in App

Tags: security, xamarin, sudo

I'm working on a Mac App which aims to install several software easilly.

To do so, I'm for instance installing Homebrew (https://brew.sh).

The problem is simple: to run scripts / installers code I found 2 ways:

1) Process.Start("thing to execute")

2) Security.Authorization.Create()... ExecuteWithPrivileges.

Actually, I'm, for instance installing HomeBrew with this code.

```
        var defaults = Security.AuthorizationFlags.Defaults;
        using (var auth = Security.Authorization.Create(defaults))
        {
            var args = new[] { "BrewInstall.sh" };
            var ret = auth.ExecuteWithPrivileges("/bin/sh", defaults, args);
        }
```

The problem I'm facing is quite simple: when I try (later on) to use HomeBrew I find out that everything has been executed with a strange user and that I cannot access to the App itself.

Is there any way to execute a portion of code as SUDO? When I try to put it into the external commands I get an error like "sudo: you must have a tty to run sudo"

I checked on the Apple docs but I can't find anything to solve this problem. If I try to change the Security.AuthorizationFlags, the system don't prompt me anymore for credentials and it's simply not working any more.

Thanks